# Meteor nested array update using $[<identifier>]

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have following document (I cannot change structure of document)

```
{
  name: "Plastic",
  items: [
    {
       collection: "Toys",
       items: [{color: "red", etc.}, ...]
    },
    {
       collection: "Window":
       items: [{color: "blue", etc.} ...]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to add items into **Toys.items**. So, as far as I understand I should use [positioned filtered operator `$[<idetifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) for mongodb update function. However Meteor update function only accepts function as following

```
Mongo.Collection#update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])
```

according to [documenation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update). So, I wonder how I can achieve similar result in meteor? In mongodb following should work:

```
db.collection.update(
   { name: "Plastic" },
   { $push: { "items.$[name].items": {color: "Red", etc} } },
   { arrayFilters: [ {"name.collection": "Toys"} ] }
)
```

P.S: My mongo db 4.0.0 and Meteor 1.7.0.3

Comment: "In mongodb following should work"  - can you confirm that it works in your mongo console?

Comment: I confirm it works well in mongo console.

Comment: Okay in this case it could be not implemented in the Meteor Mongo collection. Please try to use `collection.rawCollection` to execute this update on the native mongo collection. Does this work?

Comment: I will try it today later and post result

Comment: @Jankapunkt I can confirm that it works with rawCollection. I found issue [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10103). So, resolution of my research is "Meteor currently not supported positioned filtered operator out of box".